# Boto3 does not use specified region

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudtrail

I have the following script to list trails from CloudTrail:

```py
import boto3
import os

os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-east-2'
current_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='production')
client = current_session.client('cloudtrail')
response = client.list_trails()
print(response)
```

This only gives me the list in `us-east-1`.

I have tried setting the variable by passing it as an argument to the session and also setting it as env var on command line but it only looks at `us-east-1`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `client = current_session.client('cloudtrail', region_name='us-east-2')`

Comment: No - It was showing me us-east-2 resources but since us-eat-1 cloudtrail is multiregion I saw us-east-1 resources

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your profile does not have a region associated to it. For this reason, the session instantiation is using `us-east-1` as a default.

To fix this, explicitly specify the region name in the session instantiation:

```
current_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='production', region_name='us-east-2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it in session config which has the following:

- aws_access_key_id - A specific AWS access key ID.
- aws_secret_access_key - A specific AWS secret access key.
- region_name
- The AWS Region where you want to create new connections. profile_name - The profile to use when creating your session.

So just add region_name in your example.
See:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html#session-configurations